# Why should I set the month number to the actual month when passing to mktime?

Tags: c++

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

        struct tm dayofmonth = {0};
        int iYear = 2012;
        int iMonth = 2; // February

        dayofmonth.tm_year = iYear - 1900;
        dayofmonth.tm_mon =  iMonth;
        dayofmonth.tm_mday = 0;
        dayofmonth.tm_isdst = 0;

        mktime(&dayofmonth);

        std::cout << "Number of days for the month " << dayofmonth.tm_mon << " is " << dayofmonth.tm_mday << std::endl;

}
```

Needed to write a simple routine, to find the number of days for a given month. However, for mktime, why should I pass the actual month number instead of month number -1.

It is more confusing, that after calling mktime, the tm_mon returns month -1 instead of the original month that was passed.

Comment: But if I don't pass tm_mday as 0, then I wouldn't get the total number of days for the month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you set `tm_mday = 0`. The "zeroth" of the month (`tm_mon = 2` means March) rolls back to the last day of the previous month (February).

Yes, it is confusing that `tm_mday` is 1-based whereas `tm_mon` is 0-based. You get used to it eventually :-)